# Viz Filtering in Tooltip not working correctly

Tags: tooltip, data-visualization, tableau-api

I would like to add a Viz into a Tooltip to compare the value in a specific week with values from other years. When I do that, the Tooltip only shows 1 value from 1 year only, not the other years.

Here is the Viz I want to include.

[image]

But only 1 value gets shown.

[image]

How can I achieve this effect? Here is a link to the Tableau data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tzM8HAcMjyz3RiSzllBH5UU2JJvP9yV5/view

Comment: Please include the dimensions or measures you have used as rows and columns. From your graph it seems that you have split the date hierarchy into rows as well as columns. Also, the link to the data is inaccessible.

Comment: I updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrections to your existing sheets.
Starting with Sheet 2 (Week wise plot):

1. Drag Date to columns, Value to rows.
2. Breakdown Date hierarchy to 'DAY' by hitting the + and remove Quarter and Month.
3. Change the DAY to Week Number from drop down menu on DAY tab.
4. Drag down the Week tab to rows now.
5. Drag Date to color mark

P.S. I have added some alignment adjustments to make the plot fit into the tool tip well.

[image: Sheet 2 Changes]

Now for Sheet 1:

1. Clear your column tab.
2. Drag Date to columns break down to Week in similar way.
3. Remove Week Attribute from marks.
4. Edit tooltip as follows: `<Sheet name="Sheet 2" maxwidth="300" maxheight="300" filter="<WEEK(Date)>">`

[image: Sheet 2 Changes]

Note: Avoid making Date continuous unless relevant to your use case.
Hope this helps.